# Why do I get an error message while loading and generating a file on ArcGIS Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-2.7

Why do I get an error message while loading and generating a file on ArcGIS Toolbox? I have attached a picture of the problem below

[image: error message image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. A well-written Question will describe the software in use, the data being processed , the task, the exact steps taken, and provide the exact error message as text  in the body of the Question. This has none of these things, making it difficult to reproduce the error.

Comment: Sounds like "Input DTM" should be a raster and you are inputting a shapefile?

Answer (score 1):

`import arcpy.utils as utils` works fine for me on ArcMap 10.8. Sounds like you have a [corrupted install](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/unable-to-run-gis-tools-that-access-arcpy/td-p/329430).

Comment: Hornbydd is probably onto something with the corrupted install. The "Easiest" fix is to simply repair ArcMap from Add/Remove software. Generally issues like this occur when another version of Python was installed on the computer _After_ ArcMap was installed. So ArcMap becomes confused as to what Python it should be using.